# Converting Angular Micro-Frontend to Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-applications, mobile-application, micro-frontend

I have been looking for information on how to convert an Angular application to an Ionic app. From what I have seen this is possible in monoliths, but would it be possible to convert an Angular application with a micro-frontend architecture to an Ionic app?

I have not been able to find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been testing this weekend. In order to convert to an Ionic app we should only convert the micro-frontend of the shell application.

For more information about what is the shell in the micro-frontends and how to build the shell on Angular App:
[microfrontend-shell](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/6-steps-to-your-angular-based-microfrontend-shell/)